# Allowing only premium users to watch Youtube videos

Tags: joomla, youtube

So I have a website on Joomla and I am using the Joomlapolis community builder. Rather than uploading videos to the server is there any way of only allowing premium users to watch the videos and prevent other people from watching them?

Comment: what have you already tried code wise, based on the extension you're using?

Comment: If the videos aren't being uploaded to the server, it might be easier to answer the question if you can explain where the videos are being hosted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed another extension and manually uploaded them to the server instead.